# How to split an R dataframe such that each chunk contains every unique value of a particular factor column and every row is included in a chunk?

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a dataframe such as the one created by the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

letters_comb <- expand.grid(LETTERS, LETTERS) %>% 
  mutate(Combination = paste0(Var1, Var2)) %>% 
  select(Combination) %>% 
  sample_n(100)

set.seed(123) 
n_times <- round(runif(100, 80, 120)) 

df <- data.frame(fac_var = as.factor(rep(letters_comb$Combination, times = n_times)))
```

How can I split `df` into the maximum number of chunks, such that each chunk contains every unique value of `fac_var` and every row is included in a chunk? Solutions using `dplyr` (or other `tidyverse` packages) are particularly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `group_split()` function from the `dplyr`package.

```
library(dplyr)

df_chunks <- df %>%
  group_by(fac_var) %>%
  group_split()
```

The `group_by(fac_var)` groups the dataframe by the `fac_var` column, and `group_split()` splits the `dataframe` into `chunks` based on the groups. Each chunk will contain all the rows corresponding to a unique value of `fac_var`.

Comment: I'm looking for each chunk to contain all of the values of `fac_var`

Comment: okay. then 

```library(dplyr)

unique_values <- unique(df$fac_var)

df_chunks <- df %>%
  group_by(fac_var) %>%
  mutate(chunk_id = ceiling(row_number() / length(unique_values))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(chunk_id) %>%
  group_split()
```

Comment: then you can extract the unique values of `fac_var` using `unique(df$fac_var)`. Then, we group the data frame by ``fac_var`` and create a new variable, ``chunk_id`` using `mutate()`. The `chunk_id` assigns a unique identifier to each row, indicating the chunk it belongs to.

Comment: It is definitely possible to divide this dataframe into more than two chunks. As indicated in the question, I want the maximum number.

Comment: You must extract the unique values of `fac_var` using `unique(df$fac_var)`. Then, you create a `chunk_id` variable by repeating a sequence of numbers from 1 to the number of unique values, `seq_along(unique_values)`, and ensuring it has a length equal to the number of rows in the dataframe using `length.out = n()`.

Comment: You then use `group_split()` to split the dataframe into chunks based on the `chunk_id ` values.

```
library(dplyr)
unique_values <- unique(df$fac_var)
df_chunks <- df %>%
  mutate(chunk_id = rep(seq_along(unique_values), length.out = n())) %>%
  group_split(chunk_id)
```